# Zend Skeleton Apache failed to restart

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I'm following the guide on the official website : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html to get started with the Zend Skeleton Application.

After typing the composer commands :

```
php composer.phar self-update 
php composer.phar install
```

and setting up the virtual host, I get to the step "Restart your web server".
Apache fails to restart and when looking at the error logs in Apache2 folder :

```
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whmsg.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whtopic.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whutils.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whproxy.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:51 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whutils.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:51 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whlang.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:38:51 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/Dev Soft/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/whtopic.js, referer: http://zf2-skeleton/
[Tue Feb 18 23:40:53 2014] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Tue Feb 18 23:40:53 2014] [notice] Child 5908: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
Syntax error on line 3 of E:/Dev Soft/Zend/ZendServer/etc/sites.d/vhost_zf2-skeleton.conf:
DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
[Tue Feb 18 23:40:54 2014] [notice] Child 5908: Released the start mutex
[Tue Feb 18 23:40:54 2014] [notice] Child 5908: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Feb 18 23:40:55 2014] [notice] Child 5908: Child process is exiting
```

What's this bunch of missing files ?
What did I miss ?

vhost_zf2-skeleton.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf2-skeleton
DocumentRoot E:/Dev Soft/ZF2-Skeleton/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory E:/Dev Soft/ZF2-Skeleton/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using Windows, I think you need quotes around the paths:

```
DocumentRoot "E:/Dev Soft/ZF2-Skeleton/public"
```

you also might need to use escaped backslashes instead of forward slashes:

```
DocumentRoot "E:\\Dev Soft\\ZF2-Skeleton\\public"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Didn't think it was so simple.